# Start Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar

Tags: java, android, maven

I have some problem while start Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar. 
This project with https://github.com/WhisperSystems/PushServer.
It' s next message:

```
CAPSULE: Waiting for client to connect...
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in G:\PushServer\Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
CAPSULE: Client connection failed.
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Accept timed out while processing null null: null
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
at Capsule.startServer(Capsule.java:1717)
at Capsule.launch0(Capsule.java:1378)
at Capsule.launch(Capsule.java:1351)
at Capsule.launch(Capsule.java:1280)
at Capsule.main0(Capsule.java:399)
at Capsule.main(Capsule.java:379)
CAPSULE: Closing comm
CAPSULE: Cleanup
```

Firstly I need to know why
 
    ...
    Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in G:\PushServer\Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    agent library failed to init: instrument
    
...
it happened?
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is the capsule issue

in pom.xml change the version to newer, in my case 1.0.1

```
<!-- <capsule.maven.plugin.version>0.10.0</capsule.maven.plugin.version>-->
     <capsule.maven.plugin.version>1.0.1</capsule.maven.plugin.version>
```

from: [Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in ...\PushServer\target\Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986742/failed-to-find-premain-class-manifest-attribute-in-pushserver-target-push-se)