# Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in ...\PushServer\target\Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar

Tags: java, maven, sockets, netbeans, signals

I follow the guide to running signal server at this link:

https://github.com/lucaconte/BeatTheMeddler

When i try to run the PushServer at this step:

`java -jar Push-Server-<VERSION>-capsule-fat.jar server YourPushServerConfigFile.yml`

Then an error raised:

`Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in ...\PushServer\target\Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
CAPSULE: Client connection failed.
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Accept timed out while processing null null: null (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)`

I've been create manifest with this two scripts and also point main class to `PushServer.java` in netbeans, but the problem persist.

`jar -tf Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar`

`jar -xf Push-Server-0.12.0-capsule-fat.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this is the capsule issue

in `pom.xml` change the version to newer, in my case 1.0.1

```
<!-- <capsule.maven.plugin.version>0.10.0</capsule.maven.plugin.version>-->
     <capsule.maven.plugin.version>1.0.1</capsule.maven.plugin.version>
```

from:
https://github.com/puniverse/capsule/issues/89